# Jest.js Mocking a method within a module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm testing a generator function with Jest.js but my question is generally about mocking functions within modules.

Foo.js has:-

```
const Foo = {
   callMe() { 
     return true;
   },
   callMe2() {
     return true;
   }
};
export default Foo;
```

In my Jest test I want `Foo.callMe` to throw an error but I can't get it to work with Jest mock.

```
import Foo from '../Foo';

it('fails my generator function', () => {
  const gen = myGenFunction();
  expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(call(Foo.callMe));
});
```

The generator function looks something like this:

```
export function* myGenFunction(action) { 
  try {
    const response = yield call(Foo.callMe);
    console.log('Success');
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('Error!!!');
  } finally {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

How can I make `Foo.callMe` throw an error? I've tried a few things, but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to achieve what I wanted by using redux-saga's **throw** method.

```
it('fails my generator function', () => {
  const error = { message: 'Look see here, an error' };

  const gen = myGenFunction();
  ...

  expect(gen.throw(error).value).toEqual(
      put(actions.setIsLoading(false)), // action that happens on fail
      'gen should yield an Effect put(actions.setIsLoading(false))'
  );
});
```

It's nicely documented here: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/ErrorHandling.html